# Best way to show obligatory message to authenticated users

Tags: laravel

I would like to display an obligatory message to authenticated users. Each time the app is called (via browser), it should check whether the message has to be displayed or not (because it was already shown).
I wonder, where is the best place for such functionality. Middleware? Auth-event? What would be the best way to handle this?
The functionality about the message beeing already shown status is self evident and not part of my question.

How it should work: An authenticated user calls the route 'somethinguseful'. If there is a message available, it should redirect to the route 'messages' showing the desired content. There is a button like 'Continue'. This marks the content as shown and should redirect the user back to the route 'somethinguseful'.

BTW: This shall work for the current last version of laravel 5.8.*

Thanks for your suggenstions.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried around with middleware, but diggin deeper into this part of laravel is not yet very familiar to me.

Comment: a middleware would be the smart place to do this, so knowing that you can modify the request _and_ the response from the middleware, how would you implement this

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Then i go on with the middleware-way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @derek-pollard,  i tried on with middleware. If anyone is facing a similar situation, this is how it worked for me.

1) Create middleware, doing the logic for checking whether a message is to be displayed and redirect if necessary.

2) My little pitfall was getting the user-data inside of the middleware. But simply solve this by adding

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

to $middleware.

3) Of course add your middleware to $middleware@/app/Http/Kernel.php. Please make sure that it is inserted after EncryptCookies and StartSession.

4) To get it working only at certain routes, create an entry at $routeMiddleware or $middlewareGroups, what to do when working with more then web-routes.

I was also trying around with events. But events are really cumbersome for this task.